# Does a less sparse matrix give less accurate estimation using cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, lasso, glmnet

I am using a simple regression example
     $$Y=X\beta+\epsilon$$
$X$: 10 by 15 data matrix.
$\beta$: 15 by 1 vector.
$Y$: 10 by 1 vector.

I am using beta1 and beta2 to compare the results against each other.  Second element in beta2 is 1.  Why, after cross validation, beta2 becomes more sparse(less non-zero)?

```
library(glmnet)
beta1 <- c(0, 0, 2.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10,  0,  0,  0, -2.60,  0,  0,  0) 
beta2 <- c(0, 1, 2.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10,  0,  0,  0, -2.60,  0,  0,  0) 
X <- matrix(rnorm(10*15), 10, 15)
yhat1 <- X%*%beta1
yhat2 <- X%*%beta2
y1 <- rnorm(length(yhat1), mean=yhat1, sd=0.01)
y2 <- rnorm(length(yhat2), mean=yhat2, sd=0.01)
model1 = cv.glmnet(X, y1, nfold=3)
model2 = cv.glmnet(X, y2, nfold=3)
newBeta1 <- coef(model1)
newBeta2 <- coef(model2)
```

Results

```
> as.vector(newBeta1)[-1]   #first element is intercept
 [1]  0.00000000  0.01635715  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
 [8] -8.41872307  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000 -1.49591818  0.00000000  0.00000000
[15]  0.00000000
> as.vector(newBeta2)[-1]
 [1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -7.4082109
 [9]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.1722638  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
```

My question: beta2 is supposed to be less sparse (more non-zero elements), but why, after cv, there is more non-zero elements.  What is going on?  And why newBeta2 estimation WAY OFF?

Answer (score 1):

You are using $n=10$ observations to estimate the hyperparameter $\alpha$, the amount of shrinkage $\lambda$ and 16 coefficients (15 $\beta$s and an intercept), so you can't really expect to gain perfect estimates.

That said, I get a lot better estimates from your example by replacing 3-fold cross-validation by leave-one-out cross-validation (`nfold = 10`). The three folds are of different size and leave the train set to be rather small, so with such a limited number of observations, you are often be better off using LOOCV.

Here are the results, using your example and `set.seed` for reproducibility:

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(2882018) # current date
beta1 <- c(0, 0, 2.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10,  0,  0,  0, -2.60,  0,  0,  0) 
beta2 <- c(0, 1, 2.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10,  0,  0,  0, -2.60,  0,  0,  0) 
X <- matrix(rnorm(10*15), 10, 15)
yhat1 <- X%*%beta1
yhat2 <- X%*%beta2
y1 <- rnorm(length(yhat1), mean = yhat1, sd = 0.01)
y2 <- rnorm(length(yhat2), mean = yhat2, sd = 0.01)
model1 = cv.glmnet(X, y1, nfold = 10)
model2 = cv.glmnet(X, y2, nfold = 10)
newBeta1 <- coef(model1)
newBeta2 <- coef(model2)
round(newBeta1[-1], 2)
round(newBeta2[-1], 2)
```

Which produces:

```
> round(newBeta1[-1], 2)
 [1]  0.00  0.00  1.87  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -9.66  0.00  0.00  0.00 -2.37  0.00  0.00  0.00
> round(newBeta2[-1], 2)
 [1]  0.00  0.00  0.75  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -8.79  0.00  0.00  0.00 -1.79  0.00  0.00  0.00
```

---

As for the further shrunk estimates in `model2`, this isn't all too surprising, as the penalty:

$$(1-\alpha)/2||\beta||_2^2+\alpha||\beta||_1$$

Grows with the sizes of the $\beta$s. A simple way to show this is by choosing some $\beta$s that are smaller:

```
beta2 <- c(0, 1, 2.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5,  0,  0,  0, -2.60,  0,  0,  0) # -10 replaced by -5
```

Using the same seed and code above, this yields the following estimates:

```
> round(newBeta2[-1], 2)
 [1]  0.00  0.22  1.63  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -4.72  0.00  0.00  0.00 -2.42  0.00  0.00 -0.02
```

Even though your `model1` is in reality more sparse, it also has a smaller $\ell_1$- or $\ell_2$-norm of its $\beta$s.

---

So in short, the resulting sparsity depends on the true sparsity, the sizes of the $\beta$s and the sample size. Changing any of these changes the results as you would expect. Because of this, it also makes sense that `nfolds = 3` results in more sparse results, as the sample size of each fold is now even smaller.

---

Lastly, since the elastic net has a tendency to shrink coefficients too far, [it is recommended to multiply the resulting coefficients by $(1 + \lambda_2)$](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.124.4696).

Reference:

- Hui Zou, Trevor Hastie (2005): Regularization and variable selection via the Elastic Net